# Which module can I use to visualize Drupal log data in the format of a chart?

Tags: 7, nodes, charts

I installed [Better Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_statistics) and [Syslog Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/syslog_access). I wonder if there is a module that can take this data and visualize it like a graph, pie chart, etc? I found one but it's a service, any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Did you look on drupal.org for any modules that would be useful for you?

Answer (score 1):

## Native charting modules

Have a look at the [Comparison of Charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985). Here is a quote from it:

> There are a variety of modules that facilitate the creation of charts. When it comes to charting in Drupal, the saying "There's a module for it" doesn't really apply. In this case, it's more accurate to say, "There are plenty of modules for it" ...
>
> These modules support for various charting libraries that may be desirable based on a site's desired appearance, feature-set, and licensing needs.

Here is the shortlist of 'native' charting modules, for which **at least 1 official release** exist (quote from that comparison also):

- [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) facilitates the creation of charts  by using the [SVG Graph](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php) library. Forena does not depend on Views for creating charts, however it can be used as an extra views style plugin.
- [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart) provides a simple API to build interactive SVG charts, using the [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart).
- [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) currently only supports the deprecated [Google Chart Tools: Image Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/), which is deprecated as of April 20, 2015. Though issues [#2371567](https://www.drupal.org/node/2371567), [#2371075](https://www.drupal.org/node/2371075) and [#2368793](https://www.drupal.org/node/2368793) are about addressing that. It is the most commonly used charting module today (over 25K reported installs, which is more then double of all other native charting modules together).
- [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) (not to be confused with the charting module with namespace [chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) !!!) provides an API that can be used as a stand-alone API, and the integration with Views supports building charts with no coding.
- [Charts and Graphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts_graphs), which is an API for developers. It can be extended by third-party modules that want to add their own charting implementations. It does nothing by itself. It should only be installed if some other module requires it. [Views Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_charts) is one of the modules using it.
- [Flot](https://www.drupal.org/project/flot) provides an API and views integration for using the [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot) graphing library.

**Note**: there are quite a few additional 'native' charting modules, though they do not have an official release (yet), only dev, alfa or beta versions.

## Forena showcase

Have a look at my answer to "[Views Table with Taxonomy Terms for Columns and Rows](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180421/views-table-with-taxonomy-terms-for-columns-and-rows/180603#180603)", which details how I once created a ***crosstab*** report (using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module) that looked like so:

[image]

Then look at the video demo "[How to create Crosstab Tables and (related) charts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZY5T3kPXZc)" to get an idea what it takes to create a chart from such crosstab tables.

**Disclosure**: I'm the author of the comparison and co-maintainer of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) and [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena).