# Views Table with Taxonomy Terms for Columns and Rows

Tags: views

I have a content type for manuals that has a vocabulary for "Model Year" and another for "Model Name" with a file upload that is for owners manuals for the specific Model Name + Model Year.

I want to push this content type into a view to provide a table where the years are columns and the model names are rows with the resultant cells having the download link.

```
---------------------------------------
        | 2016     |  2015   |  2014   |
---------------------------------------
Model 1 | download |download |download |
---------------------------------------
Model 2 | download |download |download |
---------------------------------------
Model 3 | download |download |download |
```

I've been wrestling with the views all night and the table. I can't seem to get close to what I want. I've tried making sure all the taxonomy terms were added as a relationship.

If I use fields and bring the content of the year and the model forward I can display them, but not as columns, only rows and not as rolled up results in a year - so 10 2016 column instead of one 2016 columns with 10 rows.

I've tried the [Views Flipped Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_flipped_table) module, but that didn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module can be used for this type of reporting. More specifically by using its facility to create a [Display of a table in ***crosstab*** format](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.renderers#frxcrosstab).

A ***crosstab*** table is a table with a special layout. It is formatted as a grid, with:

- the **rows** representing one or more (combinations of) facts, such as countries or regions, names of persons (or users) like employees / salespeople (or user IDs / user names), **names of Models**, etc.
- the **columns** representing one or more other facts, such as periods (months of a year, **years**, etc), available types/flavors of something (like types of errors), etc.
- the **intersections of rows and columns** containing the actual information (data), such as summarized information (counts of something), timestamps, etc. and which might (optionally) **include a hyperlink to a drill-down report**.

Below is a sample of such ***crosstab*** report (including drilldown links also, i.e. the numbers in red in it):

[image]

Refer to [my comment in the Forena issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2337327#comment-9143781) for more details about the above screenshot. And/or have a look at the video about [How to generate crosstab reports with graphs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZY5T3kPXZc) (Forena also supports charting of those data, a typical related requirement ...).

In this specific case, if I was to create such crosstab table, for "*the resultant cells having the download link*" I'd create a hyperlink which would actually mention the number of manuals corresponding to the selected combination of Model Name and Model Year. And by following such link, you'd get a drilldown report with links to the actual manuals.

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

In your content type (lets pretend its called Cars) add various (1 value) download fields, like this

- download 2016
- download 2015
- download 2014

Add nodes/pages to your Cars content type

- Ford
- Ferarri
- Honda

Upload the corresponding files to each download field.

Add all the fields to your view. For field **Label** you delete the download part and just leave the year.

**No need to use taxonomy terms here.**

Comment: There is a need for the taxonomy terms for relationships for other views that are built with the same content type, at least that's the path that's already been plowed. You could provide a solution that doesn't require the use of the terms, but the content type itself needs the terms.

Comment: **Your current system is flawed**. "Model Name" should not be a taxonomy vocabulary. If you want to link or "File Under" other stuff to the respective model name, you should use Entity Reference. You need download and install the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module..

Comment: If you want years to be a taxonomy term. Then you need to create a Download content type and create new content (nodes) for each download file and do a tax term reference (which is way overkill) when you can do it my way.

Comment: The Model Name vocabulary and terms is used in other content types throughout the site. The system may be flawed if this need were the only use case, but it's a taxonomy in place that serves other purposes and does it's job well. This is a "Manual" content type, specifically used to house manuals for download, segmenting those by years and models makes a whole lot of sense to me. I do have other stuff filed under years, and I have other stuff filed under Model Name.

Comment: I'll try to build the table using your current system. I don't know if it's even possible.

Comment: sorry it's not possible to do it like you have it.

Comment: Creating a Download content type, won't work either.

Comment: Unless someone knows a way that I am not aware of, please show us the light.