# Views Grouped by Row & Column

Tags: views

In Views (Drupal 9), how can I have the first group header be the row header and the second group header be a column?

Specifically, I'm looking for functionality similar to [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/tablegroup) (only D7-dev) which provides the following results:

> [image: A HTML table with times as rows and rooms as columns]
>
> Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/tablegroup

Can we do this with a fancy view's TWIG template or do I need to alter the view results?

I've checked out:

- [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator): but it only allows one grouping and no column formatting

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180421/views-table-with-taxonomy-terms-for-columns-and-rows

Comment: I would probably use Views to group by Room, then second grouping by time, and use CSS grid to position everything to look like that table, but the problem is empty cells, you'd probably have to have some data- attribute for time or a class to be more in control of cell positioning. A twig template overriding the output by looping over all nodes and outputting table HTML is probably the best solution.